# flexslider and skrollr background-attachment: fixed; will let the slides disappear

Tags: javascript, css, attachment, flexslider, skrollr

i tried to add a parallax effect with skrollr.js to the flexslider, it all works so far.
the problem i have is that i cant set the slides to :

```
slides li { background-attachment: fixed; }
```

it will let the slides disappear. without background fixed i cant achieve the wanted effect.

i have tried to load the flexslider first and then skrollr to make sure the hight etc will be calculated by skrollr afterwards..

i also removed webkit transform in the flexslider config.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue with removing :

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; in the flexslider.css

as well as set

useCSS: false in the flexslider js settings